# why are we using @Inject annotation on top of Mongo class?

Tags: spring, mongodb

I want to know the purpose of using @Inject annotation over Mongo class.

```
@Configuration
    @EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "de.hypoport.repository")
    public class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

      @Value("${mongo.uri}")
      String mongoUri;

      **@Inject
      Mongo mongo;**

      @Override
      protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "mongostress";
      }

      @Override
      @Bean
      public Mongo mongo() throws UnknownHostException {
        return new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(mongoUri, builder()`enter code here`
            .connectTimeout((int) SECONDS.toMillis(5))
            .socketTimeout((int) SECONDS.toMillis(10))
            .connectionsPerHost(100)
            .threadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier(50)
            .readPreference(ReadPreference.primaryPreferred())
            .writeConcern(ACKNOWLEDGED)
        ));
      }

      @Override
      @Bean
      public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        MongoTemplateWithRetry mongoTemplateWithRetry = new MongoTemplateWithRetry(mongoDbFactory(), mappingMongoConverter());
        mongoTemplateWithRetry.setRetryEnabled(true);
        mongoTemplateWithRetry.logMongoWarnings(false);
        return mongoTemplateWithRetry;
      }

      @Override
      @Bean
      public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() {
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongo, getDatabaseName(), getUserCredentials(), getAuthenticationDatabaseName()) {
          @Override
          public PersistenceExceptionTranslator getExceptionTranslator() {
            return MongoTemplateWithRetry.getExceptionTranslator();
          }
        };
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

prrly you're using a framework which supports injection and also you defined mongo connection properties in an xml file! this `inject` thing would look for that definition and properties and set this variable with previously created connection with those properties! and has nothing to do with mongo!